# How do you add multiple blocks to the "can_place_on" tag?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

For example, how do I give 1 stone to myself that can be placed on grass and dirt? This is what I’ve got so far:

```
/give @s stone 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["grass"]}}
```

I haven’t figured out how to add multiple blocks yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets indicate a list, in which you can include any number of elements separated by commas. For example:

```
/give @s stone 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["grass","stone","sponge","dirt"]}}
```